# Better method of getting all columns and values without changing code when new columns are added?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on an inventory program for a multi location business.

I have it working with code like the following:

```
$res=$conn->query("SELECT cokes from dailyinv where date ='$currentDate' AND location='$Location1'");
    list($cokes1)= $res->fetch_row();
```

However, there are 61 items and two locations, plus all of the par values for each item/each store, and the quantities needed per store.

I'd like to get the program to where I can add an item once and have the par, quantity on hand, and quantity needed values be automatically added to all of the pages that require them for that item.

The dailyinv table currently has all of the items, plus a date and location column.

So basically I'd go to the add new item page and it would add the item to the inv table, the par table, and the order table. I'm looking for some sort of while fetch loop that will grab all of that and any new items that I add without having to add the item to all of the pages manually.

Right now I'm using the list function for each item, x2. Is there a function that grabs all column names and values for 1 row?

Comment: to much missing information here

Comment: Right now I'm using the list function for each item, x2. Is there a function that grabs all column names and values for 1 row?

Comment: `SELECT * from dailyinv where ...` ?

Answer (score 0):

I acheived what I wanted with the following code.

```
$itemsarray= array();


$sql = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM dailyinv";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo $row['Field']."<br>";
$itemsarray[] = $row['Field'];
}
```